# Refprop works first time, not second time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make Excel functions that can use RefProp's dlls and calculations.

```vb
Public Function enthalpy(t, p)

Dim hRef As Double: Dim sRef As Double: Dim Tref As Double: Dim pref As Double

Dim nc2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim xtemp(1 To MaxComps) As Double

hmxnme = "C:\Program Files (x86)\REFPROP\Mixtures\R404A.MIX"
hfmix = "C:\Program Files (x86)\REFPROP\fluids\hmx.bnc"

nc2 = 0
ierr = 0
herr = ""
For i = 1 To MaxComps: xtemp(i) = 0: Next

hRef = 0: sRef = 0: Tref = 0: pref = 0

Call SETMIXdll(hmxnme, hfmix, hrf, nc2, hfld, xtemp(1), ierr, herr, 255&, 255&, 3&, 10000&, 255&)
Call SETREFdll(hrf, 2&, x(1), hRef, sRef, Tref, pref, ierr2, herr2, 3&, 255&)

'Zero variables apart from T and P
q = 0: d = 0: Dl = 0: Dv = 0: e = 0: h = 0: s = 0: Cvcalc = 0: Cpcalc = 0: w = 0

nc = 3
For i = 1 To nc
    xliq(i) = 0: xvap(i) = 0
Next

For i = 1 To 3: x(i) = xtemp(i): Next

Call TPFLSHdll(t, p, x(1), d, Dl, Dv, xliq(1), xvap(1), q, e, h, s, Cvcalc, Cpcalc, w, ierr, herr, 255&)
enthalpy = h / 97.6037985507645

End Function
```

It works the first time it's called, but not another time.

I must hit the reset button in VBA then call the code again using a cell with the formula `=enthalpy(278,1500)` for instance. I've printed the arguments sent to the dlls and they are the same each time.

From the TPFLSHdll call all of the returned values, up to, and including q, are always the same no matter how many times I call the function with no reset. Values of e to w are correct the first time I call the function, and then are incorrect second, third, fourth, and so on times however they remain constant.

I have other functions using similar code but different dlls that work. I can't see how I can get a different value from a process if it is called with the same arguments unless it is linked to another value which changes on the first running only and then remains constant which subsequently throws the calculation out. This mysterious value is "cleared" by resetting and so my function works again.

Comment: Where is the array 'X' defined? I don't see it, yet you reference it. Etc. for the other undefined variables (i.e. 'd'...)

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Anything not defined in the function is in the general declarations.

Comment: It seems like you need to actually stop the execution of the libraries and recreate the objects each time the code is run.

Comment: @OilDrumAlley you could try manually resetting every variable except h at the end of the function. However, another thing might be dlls memory management issue.